# CREATE TRIGGER; Incorrect syntax near DECLARE

Tags: sql-server, syntax, triggers, declare

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Booking
ON Bookings
FOR INSERT, UPDATE

DECLARE @bef AS varchar(25)

SELECT @bef = Role
FROM Inserted, booksys.dbo.Employees
WHERE Inserted.EmployeeNo = Employees.EmployeeNo

IF NOT (@bef = 'Foreman')

BEGIN 
    RAISERROR ('Only a Foreman can do that!',16,1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

I keep getting an error message when trying t execute and create the trigger; "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure trg_booking, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'."

Also, it seems, SQL Server does not recognize the object "Inserted"?

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and Management Studio.

Comment: This trigger does not handle multi-row inserts. In these cases the memory-resident table `inserted` will contain multiple rows, then it is essentially random what value you assign to `@bef`. Also the join syntax you are using was replaced in 1992 by explicit join syntax, while it isn't wrong it is very antiquated and [there are some compelling reasons not to use it](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Changed to an Inner Join. Thanks. I think it's time to update the "code database" in my brain and stop using antique code.

Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing `As` after `FOR INSERT, UPDATE`

if you have more than one statement inside `trigger` always use `Begin and END`

```
CREATE TRIGGER booksys.dbo.trg_Booking
ON booksys.dbo.Bookings
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
as
Begin

IF Not exists ( SELECT 1 
FROM Inserted Inner Join booksys.dbo.Employees
on Inserted.EmployeeNo = Employees.EmployeeNo
where Role='Foreman')

BEGIN 
    RAISERROR ('Only a Foreman can do that!',16,1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
END
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped those errors. But it created a new one, for some reason; "Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure trg_Booking, Line 1
The object 'Bookings' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.".

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @JerriKangasniemi - Do you have a table called `Bookings` in `booksys` database

Comment: @JerriKangasniemi - Check now i have updated with fully qualified name

Comment: Yes. I have the table `Bookings` in the database. In that table, I have a column named `Foreman`, which holds the employee number of the person who made the booking. That person has to have the role of `Foreman` in the column `Role` in the table `Employees`. Does that answer make sense? I'm sorry, English is my second language.

Comment: @JerriKangasniemi - Updated based on your requirement check now

Comment: @JerriKangasniemi - if you placed a unique constraint in the Employees table across both columns `EmployeeNo, Role` and added a computed column to `Bookings` which is just the constant text `Foreman` then you could apply a multi-column foreign key between these tables and not have to have a trigger at all.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. That was just me not being able to spell properly. I do however still get an error, which I have not seen before. `Msg 2108, Level 15, State 1, Procedure trg_Booking, Line 1
Cannot create trigger on 'booksys.dbo.Bookings' as the target is not in the current database.`. I'm guessing it's trying to create the trigger inside the `master` database for some reason? I solved it by right clicking the database and targetting the correct database that way, but is there a more "idiot proof" way of doing it in the query itself?